# Installing New Relic on different servers but same repo

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, newrelic

I have a webapp with the new_relic gem. I deploy the app to heroku (app1).

Using the same code, but with different branches, I deploy to a different heroku app (app2)

at the moment, I see in the new relic dashboard that the app is running on 2 hosts. It might be that it see that same app from 2 different IPs (which it is)

how do I separate the apps such that new relic data from app1 won't mix with new relic data from app2?
the only identifier the new_relic.yml has is the license key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the data out by setting the `app_name` attribute in your `newrelic.yml` file. So the branch for app2 would just have a variant config file.

You can find a bit [more detail in the docs](https://newrelic.com/docs/general/how-do-i-change-my-application-name).